# Use python to create a nested json

Tags: python, json, nested

> {"0":{"posted_date":"25 Jun 2015"},"1":{"posted_date":"26 Jun 2015"}}

Note:

1. that '0' and '1' are variable - 'count', the variable is generate through repeat/loop
2. "posted_date" is a string
3. "25 jun 2015" and "26 jun 2015" are also variable - 'date'

How to create a JSON output like above with python?

[edit-not working code]

```
import json
final = []
count = 0
postID = 224 
while postID < 1200:
    final.append({count: {"posted_ID":postID}})
    count = count + 1
    postID = postID * 2
print str(json.dumps(final))
```

Comment: The first step : write code!

Comment: Since SO is not a code-writing-service, I'll give you some entry points: To handle json, take a look at [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module and Python's default [`dicts`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

Comment: @Kasra of coz, anyway here is my (wrong) code: look at above (edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

dates = ["25 Jun 2015", "26 Jun 2015", "27 Jun 2015"]

result = {}
for each, date in enumerate(dates):
    result.update({each: {"posted_data": date}})

jsoned = json.dumps(result)
```

You don't need to use the "count" variable

Answer (score 0):

First create the map the way you want it:

```
outMap = {}
outMap["0"]={}
outMap["0"]["posted_date"]="25 Jun 2015"
outMap["1"]={}
outMap["1"]["posted_date"]="26 Jun 2015"
```

Then use json.dumps() to get the json

```
import json
outjson = json.dumps(outMap)
print(outjson)
```